# A property of the _digamma_ function

Tags: divergent-series, digamma-function

On the last paragraph of the  article on Wikipedia about the digamma function I found [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Regularization)

*The digamma function appears in the regularization of divergent integrals*   $$ \int _{0}^{\infty }{\frac {dx}{x+a}} $$  *this integral can be approximated by a divergent general Harmonic series, but the following value can be attached to the series*  $$\displaystyle \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{n+a}}=-\psi (a) $$

There is no reference, I'd like to know where the last divergent sum value comes from.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a regularization is to subtract some (constant) infinity to be left with a finite expression possibly meaning something. In this case, the relevant formula is mentioned in the article at Wikipedia:
$$\psi (a)=-\gamma +\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left({\frac {1}{n+1}}-{\frac {1}{n+a}}\right).$$ In other words, we add the constant infinity (divergent series) $$\gamma -\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac {1}{n+1}$$ to get the hopefully meaningful function $-\psi(a).$

Comment: Makes sense only knowing that $$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{1}{a+k}-\log (n)\right)=-\psi (a)$$

Comment: Indeed, but things like that _do_ make sense in theoretical physics, often.